# alarm function in unix

Tags: c, signals

Below code does not have error but I am expecting that it should have got terminated by itself after '5 seconds (argument in alarm function)'. I think I have misunderstood alarm behaviour.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>
#define endl printf("\n")
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rc;
printf("Waiting for IOs");
getchar();
rc=alarm(5);
printf("value of rc is %d", rc);
endl;
}
```

As per definition , *The alarm function allows us to set a timer that will expire at a specified time in the future. When the timer
expires, the SIGALRM signal is generated. If we ignore or don't catch this signal, its default action is to terminate
the process*

Comment: You print out the return value from the call to `alarm()`, then your `main()` returns (without a proper return value...), and your process ends before the alarm signal is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something to wait for signals, e.g. a call to [sigsupsend(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) or [pause(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) as the last statement of your `main`. You could also have used [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) or [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), etc.. Or make some blocking I/O, or do some lengthy computation.

Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed now, I had to call alarm before I go for getchar(), so below is now fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>
#define endl printf("\n")
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rc;
printf("Waiting for IOs");
**rc=alarm(5);**
**getchar();**

printf("value of rc is %d", rc);
endl;
}
```